# Error: Conflcting types for xxx pointing to same declaration

Tags: c, interpreted-language

I've been writing a tad of C lately. I haven't had too much experience throwing everything into headers, writing their implementations, etc - but I thought I knew enough. At least, until today :P

Long story short - I'm getting an error of 'conflicting types for ValueArray' - but it points me to the same line for the previous declaration.

It repeats that for a handful of declarations in that same file, and then declarations in another file as well.

P.S. The error is not underlined in CLion as well.

```
In file included from chunk.h:2,
                 from vm.h:1,
                 from compiler.h:1,
                 from vm.c:5:
value.h:7:3: error: conflicting types for ‘ValueArray’
    7 | } ValueArray;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from chunk.h:2,
                 from vm.h:1,
                 from vm.c:4:
value.h:7:3: note: previous declaration of ‘ValueArray’ was here
    7 | } ValueArray;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is value.h:

```c
typedef double Value;

typedef struct {
    int capacity;
    int count;
    Value* values;
} ValueArray;

void initValueArray(ValueArray* array);
void writeValueArray(ValueArray* array, Value value);
void freeValueArray(ValueArray* array);
```

I've looked through my code and haven't found any redeclarations of ValueArray. I did some research - it seems like it could depend on when ValueArray is declared. To me though, it seems completely fine.

For reference, I'm following [Bob Nystrom's guide Crafting Interpreters](https://craftinginterpreters.com/compiling-expressions.html), with a bit of my own twists.

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: Maybe you have simply excluded this in the post for brevity, but perhaps the problem is value.h is missing the [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard#Use_of_#include_guards)? That could explain such an error.

Comment: Aha thank you - that was exactly it. I've seen them before, but omitted them in my code - completely my fault. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is

```
In file included from chunk.h:2,
                 from vm.h:1,
                 from compiler.h:1,
                 from vm.c:5:
value.h:7:3: error: conflicting types for ‘ValueArray’
    7 | } ValueArray;
```

but we see this next:

```
In file included from chunk.h:2,
                 from vm.h:1,
                 from vm.c:4:
```

Notice the include path is different.

It looks like you're compiling `vm.c`.  `vm.c` includes `compiler.h`, which eventually causes `value.h` to be included.

You then include `vm.h`, which ***also*** causes `value.h` to be included.

You need to use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to prevent multiple inclusion of the file:

`value.h`:

```
#ifndef MY_VALUE_H_INCLUDED
#define MY_VALUE_H_INCLUDED

(include file contents here)

#endif
```

You need to pick an identifier (`MY_VALUE_H_INCLUDED` in this example) that will be unique.  Note that starting the identifier with two underscores (`__`) or an underscore and a capital letter (`_V`) would be using values reserved for the implementation.

You may have circular references, in which case you need to use [forward declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).